# Equivalent to XMLHttpRequest timeout in synchronous JS

Tags: javascript, http, connection, timeout

Having a little bit of trouble understanding why a timeout wouldn't work in synchronous JS. My script is synchronous and I need it to be able to timeout as my exception deals with it, is it possible?

I've attempted to research it but all implementations (using setTimeout etc.) seem to just instantly run the following code and will skip trying to connect, almost as if the timeout was set to 0ms.

```
        function httpGet(theUrl) {
            try {
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
                xmlHttp.timeout = 3000;
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                NotifyUser("success", "<b>Success</b> We have synced with the server.");
                return xmlHttp.responseText;
            } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Connection failed, grabbing local");
                    NotifyUser("info", "<b>Connection Failed</b> Using local database - Edits will not be saved!(Yet)");
                    return offlinePopulate();
            } 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties
"XMLHttpRequest.timeout
    Is an unsigned long representing the number of milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated. A value of 0 (which is the default) means there is no timeout.
    Note: You may not use a timeout for synchronous requests with an owning window.
"

Comment: @NeilMunro I'm aware, that's why I'm looking for an equivalent to it in a synchronous setting. I understand it can't be done, but I'd like an explanation as to why if possible as well just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Well, synchonous AJAX requests have been deprecated, so I would imagine it's something to do with that. I don't know that for a fact though, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making it asynchronous with jquery.get

```
$.get( theUrl, function( data ) {
               //panic
            }).done(function(data) {
               console.log("success");

            }).fail(function() {
                console.log("fail");

            });
```